# Is there a jquery slider that shows the thumbnail when you hover over the pagination bullet

Tags: jquery, html, slider, responsive-design

I want to have the bullet pagination but when the user hovers over the bullet it shows the thumbnail  on top of it. is there a slider that does this already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A google search for "jquery thumbnail slider" gives me this

http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/camera/